# PHP Select rows from MySQL then compare one column with a String using Similar Text

Tags: php, mysql, string-comparison

I want to get a String from user, then select * from my table and then compare the string that user has entered with one column of whole rows that I've got from my table. if they're 10 percent similar then echo that whole row.
the code is like this but it doesn't work:

```
//this String is entered by user
$x  = $_GET['x'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE pro_avail = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {

while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 //compare the 'pro_specs' column to the string that the user has given
 $sim = similar_text($row['pro_specs'], $_GET['x'], $perc);
 if($perc > 10){
     $tem = $row;
$json = json_encode($tem);
 }
}}
else {
echo "0 results";
}
echo $json;
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change  :

```
while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

to:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

reference
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php'

Update:

change `$json = json_encode($tem);` to `$json += json_encode($tem);`
credit przemo_li

Comment: But that's not enough. `$json = json_encode($tem);` should be `$json += json_encode($tem);` too, or else each row will override json of previous one.

Comment: Tnx Man, It's almost working. I appreciate the help.